# How to determine versions of Android supported by my app

Tags: android, android-studio

I am building an app using Android Studio version 2.1.

I am testing it on a Lollipop device and a marshmallow one.
I was suggested to use support libraries, and I would like to make sure that it runs smoothly on Jelly Bean devices too.

I have looked it up, but can't quite understand if using v4 o v7 guarantees Jelly Bean compatibility (I am assuming it does, but not sure).

This is the first app I am developing and I just realised that I mistakenly used support versions in some activities, and native in others. I am fixing that.

Is there any tool which analyses all the code and then determines the earliest Android version that can run my app? Possibly giving suggestions on changes to make the compatibility broader?

All the answers I found so far confused me, they possibly require knowledge I don't yet have. I am a Java developer quickly trying to put together an app for a start up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minVersion in your manifest or gradle file determines the minimum SDK version that can use it.  If you lower that number, any API call that doesn't exist on that version will cause an error or warning.  Fix them.

BTW, KitKat is 19.  So to have KitKat as the minimum SDK you don't need to use any support versions most likely.  The best reason to do so is that it will provide a more consistent interface going forward-  fewer version specific oddities when using support versions.

Comment: I just edited my post, realising that jelly bean was Android 4 too. But your answer probably covered that, checking now where to find the gradle minVersion, I will upvote and close as soon as I find it :) Thanks

Comment: Its in your module gradle file, under defaultConfig